# Kendo UI Grid: Load data by parts

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, jquery-events

I've a **Grid** where I show data from a large database; however I need to show the **data by parts**. I meant, I have a table in my DB with 10,000 rows I want to show when the page load only the 10 first rows in my Kendo UI Grid, and the when the user **use the scroll and go back make a new query** (By block, e.g. 200-300 in the second load) and show the new data without lost the previous one.

I've seen some similar in the DataTables Framework, but with the kendo option I haven't been able to do the same.
If you need more information ask me.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called *virtualization of remote data* you have a demo in KendoUI website http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/virtualization-remote-data.html and the documentation in [enter link description here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid).

Basically, you have to define in your grid:

```
scrollable: {
     virtual: true
}
```

Comment: And your backing DataSource will have to have `serverPaging: true` and wherever you are pulling data from (web service or whatever) will need to support paging.

Answer (score 0):

```
@model IEnumerable<KendoUIMvcApplication1.Models.SiteMonitoring>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Site Monitoring";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)    
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(s => s.SiteId).Groupable(false);
        columns.Bound(s=> s.SiteName);
        columns.Bound(s=>s.SiteStatus);
        columns.Bound(s => s.UpdateTime);
        columns.Bound(s=>s.FuelLevel);
        columns.Bound(s => s.BatteryStrength);
        columns.Bound(s => s.DGStatus);
        columns.Bound(s => s.ACStatus);
        columns.Bound(s => s.DoorOpen);
    })



    ***.Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Virtual(true).Height(280))***

    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
     .Ajax()
    .PageSize(2)
    .Read(read => read.Action("Index", "SiteMonitoring"))
)
)
```

The page takes infinite time to load (doesn't load actually) when i scroll down for next records to see. Don't know what the problem is?